# Why i am getting oracle stored procedure error while inserting transaction details in a table (acct_trans)?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to perform bank tranasaction using stored procedure by doing withdrawal or deposit and storijng transaction details in second table after stored procedure.

```
---creating table to store account details----
create table Acct_master(
    accno   number,
    acname  varchar2(20),
    bal     number)
    
select * from Acct_master;
    
Insert into acct_master values(1,'kumar',10000);

--- creating second table to insert data after stored procedure runs---
create table Acct_Trans(
    TRID number,
    Ttype char(1),
    Tamt number,
    Accno number);

---created sequenece---
create sequence tseq
    minvalue 1
    increment by 1
    maxvalue 9999999;

 ---stored procedure to perform transaction---   

 declare
    v_accno aact_master.accno%type;
    v_ttype ACCT_TRANS.TtYPE%type;
    v_amt ACCT_TRANS.Tamt%type;
    v_bal acct_master.bal%type;
    v_trid acct_trans.trid%type;
    amount number(7,2);
  begin
    v_accno:=&accno;
    v_ttype:=&ttype;
    v_amt:=&amount;
    select bal into v_bal from acct_master where accno=v_accno;
    if v_ttype='w'and v_amt>v_bal then
    dbms_output.put_line('insufficient funds');
    elsif v_ttype='w' and v_amt<=v_bal then
    update acct_master set bal=bal-v_amt where accno=v_accno;
    v_trid:=tseq.nextval;
    insert into acct_trans(trid,ttype,tamt,accno)
    values(v_trid,v_ttype,v_amt,v_accno)
    elsif v_ttype='d' then
    update acct_master set bal=bal+v_amt where accno=v_accno;
    v_trid:=tseq.nextval;
    insert into  acct_trans(trid,ttype,tamt,accno)
    values(v_trid,'d',v_amt,v_accno)
    else
    dbms_output.put_line('invalid transaction');
    end if;
    commit;
  end;
```

Comment: Please don't forget to tell us also what error you get

Comment: ORA-06550: line 11, column 16:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
   date <a string literal with character set specification>
   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
   <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
   <an alternatively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing semi-colons as command terminators. Once fixed, procedure *executes* (I have no idea whether correctly or not):

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_accno  Acct_Trans.accno%TYPE;
  3     v_ttype  Acct_Trans.TtYPE%TYPE;
  4     v_amt    Acct_Trans.Tamt%TYPE;
  5     v_bal    Acct_master.bal%TYPE;
  6     v_trid   Acct_Trans.trid%TYPE;
  7     amount   NUMBER (7, 2);
  8  BEGIN
  9     v_accno := &accno;
 10     v_ttype := &ttype;
 11     v_amt := &amount;
 12
 13     SELECT bal
 14       INTO v_bal
 15       FROM acct_master
 16      WHERE accno = v_accno;
 17
 18     IF     v_ttype = 'w'
 19        AND v_amt > v_bal
 20     THEN
 21        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('insufficient funds');
 22     ELSIF     v_ttype = 'w'
 23           AND v_amt <= v_bal
 24     THEN
 25        UPDATE acct_master
 26           SET bal = bal - v_amt
 27         WHERE accno = v_accno;
 28
 29        v_trid := tseq.NEXTVAL;
 30
 31        INSERT INTO acct_trans (trid,
 32                                ttype,
 33                                tamt,
 34                                accno)
 35             VALUES (v_trid,
 36                     v_ttype,
 37                     v_amt,
 38                     v_accno);
 39     ELSIF v_ttype = 'd'
 40     THEN
 41        UPDATE acct_master
 42           SET bal = bal + v_amt
 43         WHERE accno = v_accno;
 44
 45        v_trid := tseq.NEXTVAL;
 46
 47        INSERT INTO acct_trans (trid,
 48                                ttype,
 49                                tamt,
 50                                accno)
 51             VALUES (v_trid,
 52                     'd',
 53                     v_amt,
 54                     v_accno);
 55     ELSE
 56        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('invalid transaction');
 57     END IF;
 58
 59     COMMIT;
 60  END;
 61  /
```

---

```
Enter value for accno: 1
Enter value for ttype: 1
Enter value for amount: 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks, its working now at ttype im using w for withdrawal and d for deposit, now i can see the  result

Comment: @kumar - also note that dbms_output should be used only for debugging purposes.  PL/SQL has no ability to interact with the client display.  dbms_output simply writes to a buffer, which is passed back to the client program when the procedure completes and returns control to the client.  It is then up to the client whether or not to actually do anything with it.